# Highcharts display largest Y value with smallest colum

Tags: php, javascript, highcharts

I'm stuck with Highcharts.

The main idea is to display people position in top - position 1 - highest bar, position 2- little less and so on. For example race results: 1st place highest column.

At the moment I  getting the opposite - highest position(closer to 1) is displayed as smallest column.

The way I feed highcharts with data:

```
series : [
        {
            type : 'column',
            data :params['week_top_data'],
            name: params['legend_title']
        },
```

where params['week_top_data'] is in PHP:

```
$user_returner[] = (object) array(
                        'top_position'      => $key+1,
                        'y'                 => $key+1,
                        'balloon'           => $balloon,
                        'week_start_date'   => $week['start_date'],
                        'week_end_date'     => $week['end_date']
                    );
```

I think I'm missing something with simple math..

Comment: Basicaly: get a lower position (_week bottom position_) and then use next calculation `LOWER_POSITION+1-current_people_position` as data value for bar.

Comment: Thanks Andrew D. that was helpful, got your idea. And then to display on Y axis wvlues starting from bottom with max position to 1 I passed to yAxis:{ categories: } array of positions starting from max() to 0. Looks that's what I need ;)